# Replace a certain part of the date

Tags: sql, sql-server

We are creating a demo database. So they need me to change a column having all the dates to a particular date.

Replace just the month and day and keep the year as is.

Ex: 03/12/2012, 06/19/1990

Solution: 01/01/2012, 01/01/1990

They want to make the month and date to: 01/01

My Query is as mentione below:

```
update Tablename set column = REPLACE(column, select substring(column,1,5) from Tablename ,'01/01') ;
```

but i get an  error as mentione below:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '01/01'.
```

Any help/advice would be appreciated.

Comment: What's the column definition for your date look like?

Comment: If you date is being saved as DateTime , you can't just perform string operation on it without converting.

Comment: It is just date.. I plan to convert it into a string and then perform the replace

Comment: Why would you be trying a replace on a date column?

Answer (score 4):

Don't change dates with string manipulation.  It is guaranteed to break things down the road and it's slower.

```
UPDATE TableName
SET [column] = DATEADD(year,DATEDIFF(year,0,[column]),0)
```

Answer (score 1):

as of SQL Server 2012 there is a DATEFROMPARTS function which is perfect for this ...
eg ... with @originalDate DATE, @newMonth INT, @newDay INT you could form your new date like this:

```
DECLARE @replacedDate Date;

SET @replacedDate = DATEFROMPARTS(
                    DATEPART(year, @originalDate),
                    @newMonth,
                    @newDay
                )
```

your sql is thus:

```
update Tablename 
set column = DATEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(year, column),1,1)
```

here are the sql server docs:

[DATEFROMPARTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datefromparts-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)
[DATEPART](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the erroneous `select`:

```
update Tablename
set column = REPLACE(column, substring(column,1,5) from Tablename ,'01/01');
```

However, it seems like a more appropriate approach would be using the `DATEPART` function:

```
UPDATE Tablename
SET column = CAST('01/01/' + CAST(DATEPART(year, column) AS VARCHAR) AS DATETIME)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to convert DateTime to VARCHAR if you want to perform String operation on it.
Secondly, you don't need to look for SUBSTRING. Just update DateTime column using DateTime format.

```
UPDATE TABLE SET ColumnName = CAST('Whatever Date You Want' AS DATETIME)
```